# Font display oversized in IE Compatibility Mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a page working in all browsers including IE 8/9 except when those browsers shift to compatibility mode - then any text tagged as `<p>` becomes horribly oversized - larger than `<h1>`. The `<p>` is not responding to any stylesheets or css directives as pertains to size.

jquery and jQueryUI are present on the page but not involved in (explicitly) styling my `<p>` elements.

Comment: You have an error on your page. If you want more detailed answers, you need to provide more detailed information about the page, such as a minimal version that exhibits the issue. For a starter, disable JavaScript the situation – then you will *know* whether jQuery is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jukka's premise proved correct - an unclosed H1 tag was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

This meta-tag forces IE to [display in the highest mode available to the version of Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Put it in the `<head>` section of your page.

Comment: His question says the page works in IE8/9 *except* when they're switched to compatibility mode (manually by the user, I guess?), so I don't think the meta tag will help since the page is already displaying in standard mode by default.

Comment: Yes, i'm switching manually - at page load everything looks fine - clicking the compat icon in address bar will display mis-sized font.

Comment: @justSteve: is that really a problem then? If your page loads in standard mode by default, why does it matter what it looks like in compatibility mode?

Comment: I'm using compat mode to reproduce the symptom reported by a user viewing my page with < IE7